# Error while implementing two listeners in java code

Tags: java, swing

In my code I implemented two listeners which looks like:

```
     class Try extends JPanel  implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener{
```

but shows the following error while compiling it:

```
 EmailTrial.java:29: error: Try is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
 class Try extends JPanel  implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener{
 ^
```

Kindly help on what is wrong & how to remove this error ...

Comment: You need to override interface method.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Interfaces and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class that implements an interface must implement all the public methods declared in the interface. So, you need to override `ActionListener, ListSelectionListener` methods.

```
class Try extends JPanel  implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener{

 @override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   // Action event code
 }

 @override
 public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
   // Action event code
 }
}
```